# How to change input values in order to filter data in shiny?

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I need to get in detail to make my title clear. The user upload the data, then the locations should be filtered by select button. However, the choices of selectbutton are "New York", "Washington", "Los Angeles", but the name of locations are as contractions. So, i need to change my select button inputs in order to filter my data where I am stopped up.

```
NO;Location
1.00;DC
2.00;DC
3.00;LA
4.00;NY
5.00;NY
6.00;LA
7.00;NY
8.00;DC
9.00;DC
10.00;NY
11.00;NY
12.00;LA
13.00;LA
14.00;DC
15.00;DC
16.00;DC
17.00;NY
```

updateselectinput does not help me. because it totally changes the inputs in sidebarpanel which i do not want.

ui.R

```
 library(shiny)
  shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  sidebarPanel( 

wellPanel(fileInput('file1', 'Choose File', accept=c('text/csv',    'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'), multiple = TRUE),

          selectInput(inputId = "location",label = "Choose Location",
                      choices = c('All','New York', 'Washington', 'Los Angeles'), selected = "All")
          )),
mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel( id="tabs", tabPanel("Data",value="panel1",tableOutput("filteredtable"))
                       ))    ))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   output$filteredtable <- renderTable({
    if (is.null(input$file1))
  return(NULL)
else {
  output$filetype <- renderText({
    ifelse(input$file1$type %in% c('text/csv', 
                                   'text/comma-separated-values',
                                   'text/plain', 
                                   '.csv'), 
           '', 
           HTML('<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please upload .csv    file!");</script>'))
  })}
read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header=TRUE, sep=";",
         quote='')

`uploadedfile1` <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath, sep=";")
datafiltered <- uploadedfile1

reactive({input$location <- c('All','NY', 'DC', 'LA')}) ## THIS PART IS PROBLEM!
if (input$location != "All"){

  datafiltered <- datafiltered[datafiltered$Location == input$location,]
}
datafiltered
 })})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass `selectInput` a named list for `choices`, it will display the name but return the value. In this case,

```
# ui.R
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    sidebarPanel( 

        wellPanel(fileInput('file1', 'Choose File', accept=c('text/csv',    'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'), multiple = TRUE),

                  selectInput(inputId = "location",label = "Choose Location",
                              choices = ('All' = 'All',
                                         'New York' = 'NY', 
                                         'Washington' = 'DC', 
                                         'Los Angeles' = 'LA'), 
                              selected = "All")
        )),
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel( id="tabs", tabPanel("Data",value="panel1",tableOutput("filteredtable"))
        ))    ))
```

If the user selects "Washington", `input$location` in server.R will be `'DC'`.